# System.Console resolving to incorrect namespace

Tags: c#

I have a simple console app with the namespace of

```
something.service.console
```

The problem is when I try to use

```
Console.WriteLine("something");
```

I get compile error: The Type or namespace name "WriteLine" dos not exist in the namespace something.service.console.

So unless I use

```
System.Console.WriteLine("something");
```

The C# compiler is trying to resolve the method WriteLine to the incorrect namespace ("something.service.console"). 
In this scenario is it possible to force the compiler to resolve the Console.WriteLine to the correct namespace "System" (instead of renaming my namespace :))?

Thank you.

Comment: this is because your Class is named `Console` same as the `System.Console`. You should avoid such naming

Comment: As Motivated pointed out you should avoid using class names that are already common in the framework.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, but that was not the question :)

Comment: You _must_ prepend `System`, so `System.Console.WriteLine()`. Names are resolved outwards from scope, and `YourNamespace.Console` is the first match for `Console`.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to make the compiler work the way you want. There is no way to differentiate your Console and System.Console as it is completely ambiguous. You'll either need to rename your class or continue using `System.Console`

Comment: you could also use `using Console = System.Console;` but I don't see any need for not using `System.Console.WriteLine("something");`

Comment: @Motivated imo that answers the question ("is it possible to force...?")

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Except the alias won't work unless it's something like `using SysConsole = System.Console;` At that point it's just as easy to fully qualify the namespace.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll ah I see, it only works if the compiler currently does not prefer one over the other ("...is an ambiguous reference").

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler will find the namespace `something.service` before it finds the namespace `System` so it will assume that

```
Console.WriteLine("something");
```

actually means

```
something.serviceConsole.WriteLine("something");
```

and hence your error.

Two possible solutions are to either fully qualify the namespace when you have issues like this:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("something");
```

or change the name of your namespace so it's not `something.service.console` but `something.service.somethinglese`.

Answer (score 4):

You could "force" it like this:

```
using SysConsole = System.Console;
```

Now whenever you use `Console` in is refering to `System.Console`

```
public class Console
{
    private void Test()
    {
        SysConsole.WriteLine("something");
    }
}
```

> Note: There really is nothing bad about using:
>   `System.Console.WriteLine()`
>   and you should avoid using classnames that already exist in the .NET Framework.

Comment: That won't work. Here, `Console` from `Console.WriteLine` will still resolve to the class `Console` in the shown namespace, not `System.Console`. Names are resolved outwards from the current scope, and the containing class `Console` will be the first hit.

Comment: yeah I will fix it according to the comments above !

Answer (score 2):

Using a C# 6 feature "using static" you can change the code to in order to avoid the ambiguous name `Console` without cluttering the code.

This would make sense, if a lot of `System.Console.WriteLine` calls occur in the code.

```
using static System.Console;

namespace SomeNamespace.Console
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            WriteLine("abc");
        }
    }
}
```